Mismatch input error while ingesting nested array based objects into a dataset in adobe experience platform
I am getting mismatch input error while trying to insert nested array based objects into a dataset in adobe experience platform.
The query is as follows:
insert into b_array_processed_data_wip(_spnam.profileIds,_spnam.arrayOfObjects)
SELECT
_spnam.profileIds.airB_UID as UID,
ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(_spnam.arrayOfObjects.coolestInt,_spnam.arrayOfObjects.FavDessert)) AS arrayOfObjects
FROM
b_array_processed_data_wip
GROUP BY
_spnam.profileIds.air_UID
profileIds and arrayOfObjects are both object type.
The error is as follows:
ErrorCode: 42601 queryId: 46c028bc-0d03-4724-be1d-ce46752bc260 Syntax error encountered. Reason: [line 1:49: mismatched input '.' expecting {',', ')'}]
I have tried inserting into table without column names(just to try although its not correct) and have also tried using column names without the fully qualified name but its giving error then also.

arrayofobjects is an object type in adobe experience platform.Struct is a function used in aep again to create datasets to store certain computational logic. or columns.

I see that you removed the PostgreSQL tag. Then I will remove my comment. Perhaps somebody who knows the product (I tried to add a tag for it) will know.
